# Find 2 variables

Tags: arithmetic

> Find natural numbers $q, r$ with $0 \leq r < 3$ such that $n = 3q + r$
>
> $n=22$
>
> $n$ is a natural number

So I saw there are two unknown variables there and I believe the $0 \leq r < 3$ is the key to solving it but I'm not sure how. Unless I am supposed to test it from $0$ to $2$.

In which case only when $r=1$ would we get a $q$ as a natural number. Am I correct or is this supposed to be solved another way?

Answer (score 0):

> If the sum of the digits of a number is divisible by $3$, then the number is divisible by $3$.

Chose $r$ such that $n$ is divisible by $3$.

$n=22$ Since sum of it's digits is $1$ more than $3$, therefore choose $r=1$ .

$n-r=21$ is divisible by $3$.

Therefore $r=1$ and $q= \dfrac{21}{3}=7$

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to divide $2459449$ by $3$.  $q$ is the quotient and $r$ is the remainder.  There is no reason to try different values of $r$ or do the divisibility test as $r$ will pop out.

Answer (score 0):

try considering $n-r$ for each $r$ in 1,2,3. For every option, you can sum the digits, over and over. Then check if this sum is a multiple of 3, then the original number $n-r$ is also. Finally, $q=(n-r)/3$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes r is remainder and in this question remainder is 0, 1 or 2.

Case 1 -

If r = 0

22 = 3q

q is in fraction. So rejected.

Case 2 -

If r = 1

22 = 3q + 1

3q = 21

q = 7

Case 3 -

If r = 2

22 = 3q + 2

3q = 20

q is in fraction. So rejected.

So we have q = 7 and r = 1.